# How to replace content inside <div class="definition"></div>, but not if {} is inside?

Tags: regex, perl

I need to replace the contents inside all `<div class="definition">text here</div>` with "...", but not if any `{` or `}` is found within. I've tried this with `perl`, but it seems to be deleting too much, sometimes finding the first `<div>` and last `</div>`:

```
perl -pe 's/<div class="definition">[^{].*[^<]<\/div>/<div class="definition">...<\/div>/g'
```

E.g.:

```
This is a file <div class="definition">text here</div>.
This is a file <div class="definition">{text here}</div>. This is a file <div class="definition">text here</div>.
This is a file <div class="definition">text here</div>.
```

Output:

```
This is a file <div class="definition">...</div>.
This is a file <div class="definition">{text here}</div>. This is a file <div class="definition">...</div>.
This is a file <div class="definition">...</div>.
```

How can I replace any content there, but not if `{` or `}` are found inside?

Comment: `How can I replace any content there, but not if { or } are found inside?`, post an example which replicate this.

Comment: If you're parsing HTML, you should really use a dedicate HTML parser. Regular expressions can cause all kinds of mischief when used on HTML.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to manipulate HTML. See also http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/02/parsing-html-with-perl-2.html

Comment: @ialarmedalien read http://stackoverflow.com/a/4231482/3297613 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261561/3622940

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below perl command.

```
$ perl -pe 's/(<div class="definition">)[^{}<]+(<\/div>)/\1...\2/g' file
This is a file <div class="definition">...</div>.
This is a file <div class="definition">{text here}</div>. This is a file <div class="definition">...</div>.
This is a file <div class="definition">...</div>.
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not quite a one-liner, it is easy to do the task you want with some [Mojo::DOM](http://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) magic. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature ':5.10';

use Mojo::DOM;

my $html = 'This is a file <div class="definition">text here</div>.
This is a file <div class="definition">{text here}</div>. This is a file <div class="definition">text here</div>.
This is a file <div class="definition">text here</div>.';

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $html );

$dom->find( 'div.definition' )->grep(sub { $_->text =~ m#^[^\{]# })->replace('<div class="definition">...</div>');

say $dom;
```

Output:

```
This is a file <div class="definition">...</div>.
This is a file <div class="definition">{text here}</div>. This is a file <div class="definition">...</div>.
This is a file <div class="definition">...</div>.
```

To explain what's going on:

```
# this finds all div nodes with class definition
$dom->find( 'div.definition' )

# then filter the collection of nodes by the
->grep(sub { $_->text =~ m#^[^\{]# })

# replace those nodes with '<div class="definition">...</div>'
->replace('<div class="definition">...</div>');
```